# How can I dill.dump_session() to a string?

Tags: python-3.x, dill

I want to be able to use dill.dump_session to save to a string so I can put it in a database instead of saving to a file. Is there a way to do this.

I have tried sticking a stringIO object into the filename but got an error telling me it was expecting a string.

Any suggestions???